# Arrays in PhP Problems

Tags: php, arrays

I'm creating a virtual shop with cart...
Cart is a array in `$_SESSION['carrinho']` and in this have:

```
$_SESSION['carrinho'][$produto] = $preco; //Produto:Teste;Preço:20
$_SESSION['carrinho'][$produto2] = $preco2; //Produto:Teste2;Preço:15
```

And i'm trying to parse this array in other array:

```
array(
    "items" => array(
        array(
            "title" => "Multicolor kite",
            "quantity" => 1,
            "currency_id" => "BRL", 
            "unit_price" => 10.00
        )
    )
);
```

to use na api of online serviçe to buy the item

Help me!

Sorry for english, i'm braziliam!

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: i'm tryng to convert the `$_SESSION['carrinho']` array to the second array but not success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this - iteratore over the array and combine the items with your given keys

```
$mapping = ['Produto' => 'title', 'Preço' => 'unit_price'];
$cart = [
    'items' => []
];

foreach ($_SESSION['carrinho'] as $product) {
    $item = ['quantity' => 1, 'currency_id' => 'BRL'];
    $splitted = explode(';', $product);
    foreach ($splitted as $kv) {
        list($key, $value) = explode(':', $kv);
        $item[$mapping[$key]] = $value;
    }
    $cart['items'][] = $item;
}
```

Comment: It Works, but if only have 1 item in carrinho